# Filtering has_many association results by another association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :make
end

class Make < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles
end
```

So in `MakesController#show`, I want to display all the `current_user`'s vehicles only of that particular make. Is there a way to do it on the association like so:

```
current_user.vehicles.find_by_make(@make)
```

Or am I forced to do something like:

```
Vehicle.find_by_user_and_make(current_user, @make)
```

? I know the first method doesn't work, but the second way feels a little dirty.

EDIT:
Apologies, I realized that I oversimplified the question. I'd really like to apply a class method/scope defined on Make to the association. Calling `ActiveRecord::Relation` methods, like `where`, is quite trivial. Whipped up this example on the fly, but there is a lot more going on than a simple `where` call that I'd like to do, apologies again.

Comment: `current_user.vehicles.where(:make_id => @make)`. Find will only take the first record, while where will take a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
current_user.vehicles.where(make_id: @make)
```

as ponted out by @Zippie

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
current_user.vehicles.find_all_by_make(@make)
```